# Find maximum of 9 numbers - fast

Tags: javascript

I have 9 random integer numbers. Is there a faster way how to find maximum without explicitly compare everything?

I am performing this operation milion times per frame and this is quite slow.

```
function calculateMax(a, b, c, 
                      d, e, f,
                      g, h, i){
    var max = (a > b) ? a : b;
    var max2 = (c > d) ? c : d;
    var max3 = (e > f) ? e : f;
    var max4 = (g > h) ? g : h;

    max = (i > max) ? i : max;
    max = (max2 > max) ? max2 : max;
    max = (max3 > max) ? max3 : max;
    max = (max4 > max) ? max4 : max;

    return max;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can find max with less than `O(n)` as you need to check every value tell the max number

Comment: It's impossible to find the largest number in n numbers without n-1 comparisons and up to n-1 assignments. Your bottleneck is JavaScript. Yuk.

Comment: `var num  = [99, 4, 300, 55]; Math.max.apply(null, num) `

Comment: I need to compare everything, yes, but maybe clever way without ifs? Some bitwise operations? Or precompute some pairs?

Comment: Your function outperforms `Math.max` (even when used as directly as possible) on both Chrome and IE11 (`Math.max` wins easily on Firefox): https://jsperf.com/fast-max-for-so-question

Comment: only if the numbers are kept in sorted order. Is there a limit to the range of the numbers?

Comment: @Slai They are 8bit numbers

Comment: from 0 to 255 ?

Comment: @Slai yes, 0 - 255

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The results seem rather disappointing after running few times](http://jsben.ch/sKbOz), but posting in case someone wants to do better test on other browsers, or improve (might be faster with [`SIMD` instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SIMD))

```js
function max1(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) {                   // shortened calculateMax
    var max  = (a > b) ? a : b; var max2 = (c > d) ? c : d;
    var max3 = (e > f) ? e : f; var max4 = (g > h) ? g : h;

    max = ( i   > max) ?  i   : max; max = (max2 > max) ? max2 : max;
    max = (max3 > max) ? max3 : max; max = (max4 > max) ? max4 : max;
    return max;
}

function max2(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) {
  if (a < b) a = b; if (a < c) a = c; if (a < d) a = d; if (a < e) a = e;
  if (a < f) a = f; if (a < g) a = g; if (a < h) a = h; if (a < i) a = i;
  return a;
}

//function max(a, b) { return a - ((a -= b) & (a >> 31 )); }
//function max(a, b) { return (a - b >>> 31) * b | (b - a >>> 31) * a }
function max(a, b) { return (a - b >> 31) & b | (b - a >> 31) & a }

function max3(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) {  
  return max(a, max(b, max(c, max(d, max(e, max(f, max(g, max(h, i))))))))
}

function max4(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) {
  a  =   (a - b >> 31) & b | (b - a >> 31) & a
  a  =   (a - c >> 31) & c | (c - a >> 31) & a
  a  =   (a - d >> 31) & d | (d - a >> 31) & a
  a  =   (a - e >> 31) & e | (e - a >> 31) & a
  a  =   (a - f >> 31) & f | (f - a >> 31) & a
  a  =   (a - g >> 31) & g | (g - a >> 31) & a
  a  =   (a - h >> 31) & h | (h - a >> 31) & a
  return (a - i >> 31) & i | (i - a >> 31) & a
}

var l = console.log, p = performance
var t = p.now(), m = max1(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); t -= p.now(); l(m, 1, -t)
var t = p.now(), m = max2(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); t -= p.now(); l(m, 2, -t)
var t = p.now(), m = max3(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); t -= p.now(); l(m, 3, -t)
var t = p.now(), m = max4(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); t -= p.now(); l(m, 4, -t)
```

Comment: The performance test you linked doesn't tell us much about the expected performance on varying input, unfortunately. Since the function arguments in those tests are constant literal values, the JavaScript engine will optimize them much more aggressively than in a real-world scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to use native implementation:

```
Array.max = function( array ){
    return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};

console.log(Array.max([1,2,9,8,3,2,1,2,5]));  // 9
```

cf: https://johnresig.com/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/

Comment: [Always worth testing these things.](https://jsperf.com/fast-max-for-so-question) Even if you avoid the unnecessary array creation above, on Chrome and IE11, using `Math.max` directly is *slower* than the OP's function. (It's markedly faster on Firefox, but not if you add in array creation and such as you have above.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Interestingly, the advantage of Firefox's built-in `Math.max` disappears when we do no longer keep the inputs constant. Does Firefox's IonMonkey optimize such 'constant' calls to built-in functions away?

Comment: @le_m: I [don't observe that](https://jsperf.com/fast-max-for-so-question).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Running your updated test on FF 57 shows that `calculateMax` is about 10% slower than `Math.max`. [Cyclic shifting the arguments before each call](https://jsperf.com/math-max-vs-comparison-so-question) gives the same result. However, in the original test - when the arguments are kept constant - `calculateMax` is about 80% slower.

Comment: @le_m: Sadly, jsPerf has completely messed up those tests. :-( In any case, at the end of the day, the OP's is pretty good even on FF and better on Chrome, so...